# First recurring character problem in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a problem that I have with a recurring character problem.
I'm a beginner in development so I'm trying to think of ways I can do this.

```
thisWord = input()

def firstChar(thisWord):
    for i in range(len(thisWord)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(thisWord)):
            if thisWord[i] == thisWord[j]:
                return thisWord[i]

print(firstChar(thisWord))
```

This is what I came up with. In plenty of use cases, the result is fine. The problem I found after some fiddling around is that with a word like "statistics", where the "t" is the first recurring letter rather than the "s" because of the distance between the letters, my code counts the "s" first and returns that as the result.

I've tried weird solutions like measuring the entire string first for each possible case, creating variables for string length, and then comparing it to another variable, but I'm just ending up with more errors than I can handle.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This happens because the letter `s` occurs first in statistics. You are taking a character from the word and then looping through the others to check it. This causes it to return `s` and not `t`.  Try taking count of the number of times you are looping to match characters. The one that takes minimum should be returned first.

Comment: For each match, get the sum and the difference of the indices in the string. Multiply the difference by the sum - the smallest product indicates the first recurrence. `statistics`: `s` at index (1, 6, 10), `t` at (2, 4, 7), `i` at (5, 8). `(sum, dif)` for `s`: `(7, 5) p=35`, `(16, 4) p=64`, `(11, 9) p=99`. Smallest p for `s`=`35`. `(sum, dif)` for `t`: `(6, 2) p=12`, `(11, 3) p=33`, `(9, 5) p=45`. Smallest p for `t`=`12`. `(sum, dif)` for `i`: `(13, 3) p=39`. Smallest p for `i`=`39`. Smallest p is `12`, so **t wins**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to find the first letter that recurs in your text, with "first" being determined by the recurrence, not the first occurrence of the letter? To illustrate that with your "statistics" example, the t is the first letter that recurs, but the s had its first occurrence before the first occurrence of the t. I understand that in such cases, it's the t you want, not the s.

If that's the case, then I think a set is what you want, since it allows you to keep track of letters you've already seen before:

```
thisword = "statistics"
set_of_letters = set()
for letter in thisword:
    if letter not in set_of_letters:
        set_of_letters.add(letter)
    else:
        firstchar = letter
        break
    
print(firstchar)
```

Comment: This will throw `NameError: name 'firstchar' is not defined` for strings with no recurring characters.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're looking at a certain character in the word, you should not check whether the character will occur again at all, but whether it has already occurred. The algorithmically optimal way would be to use a `set` to store and look up characters as you go, but it could just as well be done with your double loop. The second one should then become `for j in range(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your problem (one was already provided), but an advice for a better solution:

```
def firstChar(thisWord):
    occurrences: dict[str, int] = {char: 0 for char in thisWord} # At the beginning all the characters occurred once
    for char in thisWord:
        occurrences[char] += 1 # You found this char
        if (occurrences[char] == 2): # This was already found one time before
            return char # So you return it as the first duplicate
```

This works as expected:

```
>>> firstChar("statistics")
't'
```

---

**EDIT**:

```
occurrences: dict[str, int] = {char: 0 for char in thisWord}
```

This line of code creates a `dict`ionary with the `char`s from `thisWord` as keys and `0` as values, so that you can use it to count the occurrences starting from `0` (before finding a char its count is 0).

Comment: Can you help me understand the second line of code a bit better?
I know you are declaring a dictionary with the first element being a string and the second an integer.

What I don't quite get is this bit: {char: 0 for char in thisWord}

Comment: Yes, I'm going to explain this better.